# Mongoose's lean usage with populate and nested queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Im coding an app in Node.js which is using MongoDB. I chose MongooseJS to handle my DB queries.

I have two collections that are referenced to each other (`Room` which is the 'superior' collection and `DeviceGroups` which is contained within `Room` collection).

I have a query that gets a list of all of the rooms from `Room` collection, populates `deviceGroups` field (which is the `Rooms` reference to `DeviceGroup` collection) and inside it there is a `map` method that goes through every room found in the `Room` collection and for every room it makes another query - it looks for any `deviceGroups` in `DeviceGroup` collection that are referenced to the current room in the map method.

My goal here is to return a list of all of the rooms with `deviceGroups` field filled in with actual data, not only references.

What I am getting after the queries (inside the `then` method) is a Mongoose document. The whole algorithm is used as a handler of a `GET` method, so I need a pure JavaScript object as a response.

Main goal I want to achieve is to get result of all of the queries and population inside them as pure javascript object, so I can create a response object and send it (i dont want to send everything that db returns, because not all of the data is needed for this case)

EDIT:

I am so sorry, I have deleted my code and didnt realize it.

My current code is below:

Schema:

```
const roomSchema = Schema({
  name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Room name not provided']
  },
  deviceGroups: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'DeviceGroup'
  }]
}, { collection: 'rooms' });

const deviceGroupSchema = Schema({
    parentRoomId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Room'
    },
    groupType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['LIGHTS', 'BLINDS', 'ALARM_SENSORS', 'WEATHER_SENSORS']
    },
        devices: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'LightBulb'
        }
    ]
}, { collection: 'deviceGroups' });
```

Queries:

```
app.get('/api/id/rooms', function(req, res) {
    Room.find({}).populate('deviceGroups').lean().exec(function(err, parentRoom) {
        parentRoom.map(function(currentRoom) {
            DeviceGroup.findOne({ parentRoomId: currentRoom._id }, function (err, devices) {
                return devices;
            });
        });
    }).then(function(roomList) {
        res.send(roomList);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where are you confusing. here is a simple and effective code snippet

```
Room.findById(req.params.id)
.select("roomname")
.populate({
    path: 'deviceGroup',
    select: 'devicename',
    model:'DeviceGroups'
    populate:{
        path: 'device',
        select: 'devicename',
        model:'Device'
        }
})
.lean()
.exec((err, data)=>{
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: I am really sorry, I have somehow forgotten to post the current code. It is added to the post now

Comment: still answer respceting your current code. it's not good practics to query in database inside map. populate do same thing. read more about mongooose populate. you can skip 2nd nested populate

Comment: Thank you! I changed `populate` method's invocation to fit my needs, but your implementation works perfect for me! I read the mongoose's documentation about populate method, but it was still a little bit confusing for me. Everything is perfectly clear now.

Comment: happy coding :)